# DRY errors with multiple models in a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have kind of a lot of code in my Rails controllers that looks roughly like this:

```
errors = []

thing = Thing.create(thing_params)
errors += thing.errors.full_messages

whatever = Whatever.create(whatever_params)
errors += whatever.errors.full_messages

render json: errors
```

Obviously this is just an illustration but I think it gets the point across. It feels very un-Railsy to have to do the `errors = []` and `errors += object.errors.full_messages` in so many places in my code.

Is there kind of a standard way to DRY this up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my own answer because nothing better has immediately popped up, although I'll accept someone else's answer if it's better.

I added some functions to my base controller.

```
class Api::V2::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :base_init

  def base_init
    @errors = []
  end

  def capture_errors(resource)
    @errors += resource.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

This allows me to do something like the following:

```
class Api::V2::FooController < Api:V2:BaseController
   def create
     thing = Thing.create(thing_params)
     capture_errors(thing)

     whatever = Whatever.create(whatever_params)
     capture_errors(whatever)

     render json: @errors
   end
end
```

For easy comparison, here's the original:

```
class Api::V2::FooController < Api:V2:BaseController
   def create
     errors = []

     thing = Thing.create(thing_params)
     errors += thing.errors.full_messages

     whatever = Whatever.create(whatever_params)
     errors += whatever.errors.full_messages

     render json: errors
   end
end
```

It's not a HUGE improvement but I do think it's better.

Comment: I see where you're going to, now. I updated my answer.

Comment: simple way to add errors using array and concatenating them when needed...the only problem here is that it will need a custom html to display this error...

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a very specific scenario, and I don't think there is an idiomatic way to it in Rails.

I guess you could DRY things up a little with the *splat* operator `*`:

```
thing    = Thing.create(thing_params)
whatever = Whatever.create(whatever_params)

errors = [
  *thing.errors.full_messages,
  *whatever.errors.full_messages
]

render json: errors
```

Or you could iterate over the models you're trying to create:

```
errors = [thing, whatever].map do |obj|
  obj.errors.full_messages
end.flatten
```

---

### Update after reading the Asker's own answer

I think now I know what you are looking for.
You could DRY your answer up with this:

```
class Api::V2::BaseController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :base_init


  def create
    thing    = capture_errors { Thing.create(thing_params) }
    whatever = capture_errors { Whatever.create(whatever_params) }

    render json: @errors
  end


  private

  def base_init
    @errors = []
  end


  def capture_errors(&block)
    resource = yield
    @errors += resource.errors.full_messages
    resource
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I might challenge the idea that it's very specific; it's a problem I've dealt with on a number of different projects over a span of years.

Comment: I see. When I have chains of ActiveRecord model creations and updates I wrap them in transactions. Then, yes, I return and display the most appropriate error message, but I would not _press on_ after the first error.

Comment: Yes, I do the same. But it's possible that you have three operations, each of which might potentially, have a validation error, and the first two are valid and the third is not. I don't see any way around accounting for the possibility of an error at each step.